# Add pagination to custom search page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am a debutant in WordPress. I have a custom WordPress search page and I want to add pagination my loop.

```
<div class="content active" id="panel1">
    <?php
    global $paged, $wp_query, $wp;
    $args = wp_parse_args($wp->matched_query);
    if ( !empty ( $args['paged'] ) && 0 == $paged ) {
        $paged = $args['paged'];
    }

    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $wp_query->query('post_type=post&s='.$keyword.'&posts_per_page=5&paged='.$paged.'&cat='.$catSearchID);
    //print_r($wp_query);exit();
    $current = -1;
    $current2 = 0;
    $emptyPost2 = 0;
    ?>
    <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div><!-- END panel1-->
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php get_template_part('pagination'); ?>
</div><!-- END tabs-content-->
```

My template pagination :

```
global $wp_rewrite;         
$wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query-    >query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;

$t_pagination = array(
    'base' => @add_query_arg('page','%#%'),
    'format' => '',
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'current' => $current,
    'show_all' => false,
    'type' => 'plain',
);

if($wp_rewrite->using_permalinks())
    $t_pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit(     remove_query_arg('s',get_pagenum_link(1) )) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged');

if(!empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']))
    $t_pagination['add_args'] = array('s'=>get_query_var('s'));

echo '<div class="pagination">' . paginate_links($t_pagination) . '</div>';
```

I tried a lot of solutions but it give in second page 404 error.

Comment: are you getting query result?

Comment: for first page i get the results but in second page i get 404 error page

Comment: I am asking for query not regarding page.

Comment: when i open  
http://localhost/wp2/wordpress/page/1/?s=&category_name=All&post_location=Grand+Casablanca&search=Search
i get the query result 
when i open 
http://localhost/wp2/wordpress/page/2/?s=&category_name=All&post_location=Grand+Casablanca&search=Search
404

Comment: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/wordpress-pagination-gives-404-unless-i-set-blog-pages-show-at-most-to-1-in-reading

Comment: I have the same problem. It returns error 404 when in page 2